# Php PDO request for data from the sum of a derived table column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Here is an SQL query that I am attempting to use in some php PDO code:

```
SELECT SUM(credit_hours) AS hours FROM(SELECT Course_List.credit_hours FROM Program_Courses,    Course_List 
WHERE program_id= :pid and concentration_id= :conid 
and fulfills_major=1 and Program_Courses.course_id = Course_List.course_id ) AS major_credits
```

When I run this query on my database in SQL Workbench I get a derived table with a single column named
"hour" and a single row with the value 76 in it.

Here is the php code I'm using to try to get this same data stored in a variable $major_hours:

```
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE username = :un");    
    $result->bindParam(':un',$user);
    $result->execute();
    $data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   //returns an associated array where the indices are the column names
    $program = $data['program_id'];
    $concentration = $data['concentration_id'];

    //get the total number of credit hours in the student's major/concentration
    $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT SUM(credit_hours) AS hours FROM(
                                SELECT Course_List.credit_hours FROM Program_Courses, Course_List 
                                WHERE program_id= :pid and concentration_id= :conid 
                                and fulfills_major=1 and Program_Courses.course_id = Course_List.course_id 
                                ) AS major_credits");
    $result->bindParam(':pid',$program);
    $result->bindParam(':conid',$concentration);
    $result->execute();
    $major_hours = $result->fetchColumn();
```

I know that the variables $user, $program, and $concentration all have legitimate values because when I echo those to the page, I get the correct result. However, echoing $major_hours gives absolutely nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add some `return` ? 
`return $major_hours`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**fetch**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) as you may guess it fetches the next row from a result set
The fetch_style parameter determines how `PDO` returns the row, in your case `FETCH_ASSOC` would be a good one since it returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set.

```
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//row is an associative array
$major_hours = $row['hours'];           //access the column name hour
echo $majors_hours;                     //will print the hour value from db
```

Comment: Thank you, Krishna and meda. That worked splendidly!

Answer (score 0):

I have not used sql workbench, but you may want to use isnull() or coalesce() on your SUM(credit_hours) expression.  I think that should result in $major_hours showing 0.

Comment: I tried both IFNULL() and COALESCE() surrounding SUM(credit_hours),0 and still the page is showing nothing

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
$major_hours = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $majors_hours['hours'];
```

There is 2 way to return a data from database. `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Fetch only return 1 row from database .. but fetchAll will return all row from the database query you make.

And `(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` it means will return the data with an array.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.